# “Fortemente voluto”

Tags: history

Osservo che in tempi recenti si è molto diffusa la locuzione “fortemente voluto”, specie in “aziendalese” e “politichese”, in frasi del tipo (prendo quasi a caso da Google Books):

> È uno dei rari esempi di collaborazione transfrontaliera di tipo bottom-up, fortemente voluto dagli operatori locali.
>
> Fortemente voluto proprio in questi mesi dal Ministro Profumo il programma propone una grande possibile interazione...
>
> È un risultato fortemente voluto in oltre mezzo secolo di impegno dalle forze politiche, economiche e sociali del Friuli-Venezia Giulia...

(ometto le citazioni specifiche perché non mi interessano le singole istanze, quanto il tipo di contesto in cui si adopera).

Una [consultazione dell'Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fortemente%20voluto&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfortemente%20voluto%3B%2Cc0) di Google Books conferma empiricamente che, con la diffusione attuale, è un fenomeno relativamente recente, decollato negli anni Ottanta e asceso rapidamente:

[image: Grafico dell'ascesa dell'uso di “fortemente voluto”]

Ora: qualcuno sa che cosa abbia provocato questa rapida ascesa dell'uso di “fortemente voluto”? È un calco da qualche espressione in un'altra lingua? Lo usò qualche personaggio famoso?

Comment: A me viene in mente il  "Volli, e volli sempre, e fortissimamente volli" di Alfieri, però risale a 200 anni prima.

Comment: Davvero notevole la popolarità di  questa espressione negli ultimi anni, non ci avevo fatto caso. Difficile individuarne l'origine, ci sono parole o espressioni che diventano improvvisamente molto usate  forse a causa dei media, mi viene in mente "piuttosto che" o "sinergico" ma ce ne sono molte altre.

Comment: Ottima domanda. Sarei curioso di capire anche il flesso improvviso attorno al 2007: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fortemente+voluto&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cfortemente%20voluto%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfortemente%20voluto%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFortemente%20voluto%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Parliamo di un balzo da 0.0000050% 0.0000350%; nonostante sia considerevole a livello di grafico è a mio parere insignificante a livello di percentuale.

Comment: @momomorez, non sono sicuro di riuscire a vedere i numeri precisi che dici, ma è il meno. Intanto stiamo parlando della frequenza, neppure di una parola, ma di un'espressione formata da due parole, e quindi è chiaro che le percentuali siano infime. Poi, se diamo credito ai dati di Google Books (che vanno presi con le molle per vari motivi), abbiamo un fenomeno che per più di un secolo ha mantenuto una frequenza più o meno costante la quale poi nel giro di venti anni decuplica: dal punto di vista relativo è un aumento enorme.

Comment: Non ho una risposta ma una possibile interpretazione, quindi mi limito ad aggiungere un commento.

È possible che si tratti di un ["meme" alla Richard Dawkins](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme) che si è riprodotto esponenzialmente solo a partire dagli anni '80, magari perché utilizzato nel linguaggio politico televisivo.

Comment: Riguardo "un calco di un'espressione in un'altra lingua", posso dire che in inglese è molto diffusa l'espressione "highly desirable" che secondo me può avere un significato deviante quando il giudizio espresso non viene attribuito. Però nelle frasi esemplari qui, si cerca di includere l'attribuzione.

Comment: Su _Linkiesta_ è apparso un articolo piacevole sulla locuzione “fortemente voluto”, che però non aggiunge molto a quello che si è già detto qui: https://www.linkiesta.it/2023/05/fortemente-voluto-questa-cosa/

Answer (score 0):

La rapida ascesa dell'uso di “fortemente voluto” nel corpus di Google dipende dal fatto che le ivi presenti pubblicazioni comprendono dagli '80 in poi tipologie o raccolte 'letterarie' prima assenti.

Cioè, in altri termini, nello scritto e nel parlato reale non c'è stato alcun incremento esponenziale nell'uso della predetta locuzione. Siamo, piuttosto, di fronte ad una distorsione dovuta al processo di formazione del corpus di Google.

Comment: Può avere senso, ma siamo d'accordo che avere un grafico del genere significa che, a parità di incidenza del termine, è il numero di opere indicizzato nel tempo ad avere quell'andamento regolare e quasi esponenziale? Trovo un po bizzarro anche quello, ma magari mi sto perdendo qualcosa io. Oltre tutto ti chiedo "siamo d'accordo" perché non hai messo nessun link ad una fonte, potresti aggiungerlo? Se tu lo facessi probabilmente ogni dubbio sarebbe fugato.

Comment: Non c'entra il numero di opere raccolte, perché il grafico mostra una frequenza percentuale. Quanto all'ipotesi di Elberich, è possibile, ma a priori non capisco perché sia più probabile dell'“ipotesi zero”, e cioè che ci sia stato un vero, forte aumento dell'uso dell'espressione (che riscontro anche nel parlato, nei giornali etc.).

Comment: @DaG Non sono stato preciso, intendevo *il numero di opere contenenti il termine sul totale delle opere*. Oltretutto non so se hai notato l'altro link che ho postato sotto la domanda, a dirla tutta *sembrerebbe* un artefatto dovuto a ragioni di indicizzazione (anche?) quello.

Comment: Stiamo sempre parlando di percentuali, quindi aumentano anche le opere in cui NON compare fortemente voluto. A me viene da pensare che, parlando di percentuali talmente basse, questa variazione sia dovuta a qualche autore a cui piaceva particolarmente l'espressione, non ha fenomeni culturali particolari. (idee mie, eh. magari e molto probabilmente sbagliate)

Comment: È chiaro che Google Books (e gli Ngram che su di esso si basano) non va preso a scatola chiusa, ma, se non abbiamo motivazioni specifiche per ritenere che qualche loro indicazione è falsata, ogni considerazione del genere è puramente arbitraria e personale. Quanto ai valori assoluti, per il solo 1999, “fortemente voluto” viene trovato in 34 libri di vario genere e per il 2000 in 38. Quindi è difficile supporre che basti l'effetto di uno o pochi autori.

Comment: @kos - Forse mi sfugge qualcosa, ma cos'è che farebbe sembrare a un artefatto dovuto all'indicizzazione? Fino a prova contraria, trovo verosimile che ci sia stata davvero una crescita fino al 2000 e poi una decrescita. (L'unica attenzione va posta sul fatto che in genere vediamo i grafici con uno “smoothing”: se lo poniamo a 0, il profilo del grafico è molto più frastagliato, ma l'andamento generale non cambia.)

Comment: @Paolo Il corpus di Google non è scelto in modo casuale, ma secondo gli orientamenti politico-culturali di chi sceglie, di talché è proprio il contrario: è quel 'fortemente voluto' - tipico di certo culturalismo - che smaschera il giochino.

Comment: @DaG Forse ho inferito conclusioni troppo azzardate io nel giudicare l'andamento generale del grafico. L'idea era che se l'andamento del grafico fosse proseguito in declino avrebbe contraddetto la tua ipotesi iniziale (con la quale invece concordo), ovvero che l'uso del termine sia stato in crescita fino ad oggi (e particolarmente negli ultimi anni); se fosse risalito come da ipotesi avrei trovato bizzarro il gap (i.e. artefatto?), perché non sarebbe stato per nulla simile all'andamento tipico di un "trend", ma ora leggo nel tuo commento sopra che si parla di una trentina di libri.

Comment: @DaG Non so nemmeno come hai fatto a vedere il numero esatto, ma ho supposto (sbagliando) che il campione fosse molto più grande. Se si parla di un numero così basso allora certo, quel gap è irrilevante.

Comment: @kos: Se l'andamento in discesa degli ultimi anni sia reale o no è – ai fini della mia domanda – il meno: se vuoi la riformulo restringendola al periodo 1980-2000.

Comment: guarda che facendo l'Ngram Viewer sloggato dal mio account mi vengono gli stessi risultati. Quindi non centra nulla con gli orientamenti "politico culturali"

Comment: L'osservazione sulla trentina di libri era rivolta soprattutto a @PaoloZaia: trovo che il fatto che una certa espressione sia presente in un numero di libri dell'ordine delle decine all'anno, sul campione di Google che non comprenderà tutti i libri usciti, non sia irrilevante; non si tratti cioè di un fenomeno alterato da uno o pochissimi autori.

Comment: Infine, quanto al numero esatto fornito da Google: ho cercato su [Google Books restringendo l'intervallo di tempo che mi interessava](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fortemente+voluto%22&lr=lang_it&newwindow=1&safe=off&biw=1280&bih=701&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1it%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2000%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2000&tbm=bks#lr=lang_it&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbs=lr:lang_1it%2Ccdr:1%2Ccd_min:1%2F1%2F2000%2Ccd_max:12%2F31%2F2000&tbm=bks&q=%22fortemente+voluto%22) e poi sono andato all'ultima pagina dei risultati i quali, almeno nella mia visualizzazione, sono 10 a pagina.

Comment: @DaG secondo me parlando di google books in Italiano puo' incidere, fosse in lingua inglese inciderebbe molto meno. Dopotutto proprio non avendo google books un'ampia e completa scelta, e' piu' facile in termini probabilistici che il dato risulta falsato! (se tiri una moneta 10 volte possono uscirti anche 9 volte testa e una croce, se la tiri 100 sia avvicinera' di piu' al 50-50.. diminuendo il numero di campioni  e' piu' facile che ci siano dati alterati)

Comment: @DaG Trovo anch'io che non sia irrilevante. Trovo anche non sia indispensabile reiterare la domanda in funzione del gap ormai dichiarato irrilevante, comunque a questo punto non ho proprio capito bene se la domanda vuole riferirsi anche a tempi più recenti (per dire un anno a caso dal 2010 ad oggi). Grazie per la dritta sui numeri (comunque, in una nota a parte, ho provato a cliccare sul 10 e il numero massimo di pagine è sceso a 5, quindi se vogliamo c'è anche un bug da aggiungere all'equazione).

Comment: @charo, questa discussione andrebbe trasferita in chat. Sarebbe anche un modo per promuoverne l'uso.

Comment: @paolo, non mi riferivo agli orientamenti degli utilizzatori, ma a quelli dei selezionatori presso Google.

Comment: Può que la natura del corpus abbia cambiato? Dopo li '80 ci sonno più testi di tipo che contiene queste espressione?

Answer (score 0):

Premesso che quanto segue è solo un'ipotesi personale e che non ho alcuna competenza linguistica o filologica per fare alcuna affermazione al riguardo, credo che il fenomeno possa essere spiegato, almeno in parte, dall'evoluzione dei costumi e della mentalità nel tempo.

Ricordo che, quando da bambino dicevo "voglio", nove volte su dieci i miei nonni mi rispondevano che "*l'erba voglio non cresce neppure nel giardino del re*".
Consideravano "voglio" un'espressione "forte", quasi maleducata, come se si esprimesse una pretesa più che una volontà, ed era abbastanza comune esprimere una volontà con termini meno netti (augurarsi, caldeggiare, etc.).

Nel tempo questa attitudine è cambiata. Credo che due fattori determinanti possano essere stati il boom economico ed i movimenti degli anni '68 e '77: il primo ha messo molte più persone nelle condizioni materiali di poter volere qualcosa, mentre i secondi hanno contribuito a sdoganare dal punto di vista culturale l'idea che si potesse lecitamente volere qualcosa e chiederlo a gran voce.

E' possibile che, quel "fortemente" sia entrato in auge e divenuto via via più comune man mano che "volere" ha perso la forza intrinseca che aveva prima, diventando una neutra espressione di un desiderio.